# Apache flink join: What is "KeySelector" (Scala)?

Tags: scala, join, apache-flink

I am trying to join two data streams in Apache Flink [1]. Can someone explain what I need to put in as `KeySelector` ? It is not clear to me from the documentation. (I am new to scala as well).

*I assume these are the keys used for the join. My messages are simple json dicts, e.g.*

```
{
    "sessionId": "1234",
    ..
}
```

[1] https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/joining/#window-join

Comment: On which property of your JSON do you want to join?

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for union of two streams rather than join?

Comment: I am looking for a `left outer join` with a `SlidingEventTimeWindow` :)